# Tensorflow fully_connected not working in unit test cases?

Tags: unit-testing, tensorflow

I must missed something basic. Here is my test case -

```
    def test_silly(self):
        with self.test_session() as sess:
            init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
            out = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
                inputs=tf.zeros([self.batch_size, 10]),
                num_outputs=20,
                activation_fn=None,
                scope="hmmm")
            sess.run(init_op)
            print(out.eval())
```

I do not understand why I kept getting error like below.

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value hmmm/weights
 [[Node: hmmm/weights/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@hmmm/weights"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](hmmm/weights)]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hmmm/weights` are not initialized.

```py
def test_silly(self):
    with self.test_session() as sess:
        out = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
            inputs=tf.zeros([self.batch_size, 10]),
            num_outputs=20,
            activation_fn=None,
            scope="hmmm")
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init_op)
        print(out.eval())
```

Swapping the position of `init_op` will make it work. Refer to [What does tf.global_variables_initializer() do under the hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047929/what-does-tf-global-variables-initializer-do-under-the-hood) for more insights.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know